Partial Alignment of Shiny Datatables
I have two tables that I want to stack vertically. The lower table contains raw data and the top contains summary stats of the raw data. The wrinkle is that the lower table has an extra column on the far right that does not exist in the summary table. I would like the tables to align for the first N columns, with column N+1 in the lower table "sticking out" to the right. This feels awkward to explain, so I made a visual example in Excel.
Below is a simple, reproducible Shiny example, followed by the Excel example of what I would like it to do.
library( shiny )
library( data.table )
library( matrixStats )

ui = fluidPage(
    mainPanel(
        DT::dataTableOutput( "stats" ),
        HTML( "<br>" ),
        DT::dataTableOutput( "raw" )
    )
)

server = function( input, output ){
    
    set.seed( 123 )
    raw = data.table( Item = c( "ABC", "DEF", "LMO", "XYZ" ),
                      Data1 = runif( 4, 1, 1000 ),
                      Data2 = runif( 4, 1, 1000 ),
                      Data3 = runif( 4, 1, 1000 ),
                      Data4 = runif( 4, 1, 1000 ),
                      Note = c( "Some notes are quite short", "Some notes could be very long, perhaps up to 100 or 150 characters", NA_character_, NA_character_ )
    )
    
    cols = colnames( raw )[ 2:5 ]
    stats = data.table( min = colMins( as.matrix( raw[ , ..cols ] ) ),
                        mean = colMeans( as.matrix( raw[ , ..cols ] ) ),
                        median = colMedians( as.matrix( raw[ , ..cols ] ) ),
                        max = colMaxs( as.matrix( raw[ , ..cols ] ) ) )
    stats = data.table( t( stats ), keep.rownames = T )
    colnames( stats ) = c( "Stat", cols )
    
    raw = DT::datatable( raw, rownames = F, filter = "none", options = list( dom = 't', iDisplayLength = -1 ) )
    stats = DT::datatable( stats, rownames = F, filter = "none", options = list( dom = 't', iDisplayLength = -1 ) )
    
    output$raw <- DT::renderDataTable( raw )
    output$stats <- DT::renderDataTable( stats )
}

shinyApp (ui = ui,server = server )

An example in Excel is below:


Your best bet is to set the width of the columns by hand and making sure that you also specify a total width:
ui = fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    DT::dataTableOutput("stats", width = "1000px"),
    tags$br(),
    DT::dataTableOutput("raw", width = "1200px")
  )
)

# [...]
raw = DT::datatable(
  raw, 
  rownames = FALSE, 
  filter = "none", 
  options = list(
    dom = "t", 
    iDisplayLength = -1, 
    autoWidth = TRUE,
    columnDefs = list(
      list(width = '200px', targets = "_all")
    )
  )
)
stats = DT::datatable(
  stats, 
  rownames = FALSE, 
  filter = "none",
  options = list(
    dom = "t", 
    iDisplayLength = -1, 
    autoWidth = TRUE,
    columnDefs = list(
      list(width = '200px', targets = "_all"))
  )
)

Result


Thanks for this. I tried changing the targets (as shown here: https://rstudio.github.io/DT/options.html) to set individual columns to a different width, but I can't seem to make it work. How would I, for example, set the Note column to 400px and the others to 200px?
